# Does a counting process allow a state change by more than 1 in a single transition?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

1. [The definition of a counting process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_process)

   > A counting process is a stochastic process $\{N(t), t ≥ 0\}$ with values that are positive, integer, and increasing:
   >
   > - $N(t) ≥ 0$.
   > - $N(t)$ is an integer.
   > - If $s ≤ t$ then $N(s) ≤ N(t)$.
   >
   > If $s < t$, then $N(t) − N(s)$ is the number of events occurred during the interval $[s, t ]$.

   Per the definition, it seems to me that in a transition from one
   state to another, a counting process allows the change of the state
   to be more than 1, e.g. from a state 1 to a state 3. is it correct?
2. In a Poisson process,  the change of the state in a transition must
   be increasing by 1.

   In a birth and death process, the change of
   the state in a transition must be by 1 (either increasing or
   decreasing).

   Then are there concepts/names for these kinds of special counting
   processes which a Poisson process and a birth and death process
   belong to?

Comment: well, one could simply take a deterministic step function to be our stochastic process (with steps higher than unit 1, something like a heaviside function), this would certainly fulfill the properties of the definition and therefore we have our counting process with steps bigger than 1 - of course there wouldn't be any randomness left...

Comment: thanks. do you know the names for those special counting processes that can change by 1 in a single transition?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked for a definition of counting process which is more "constructive" than your one, I found [this (German Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%A4hlprozess) which references to [this book, German again](https://books.google.de/books?id=h7Tpex-Hw_EC&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false).

So what they are stating is: Assume we have a sequence of almost surely positive random variables $(Z_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ and we define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Z_k$, then the process
$$
X_t:=\sup\{n\in\mathbb{N}_0:S_n\leq t\},\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_0
$$ 
is called a counting process.
If we are arguing starting from this definition, then every counting process jumps by the unit of $1$, and the properties of the definition you gave are still satisfied. Your second question would then be obsolete.

In general I think I am in favor for the definition I just stated, it seems to be more natural in a counting way.

bests